# uv mapping is wierd

Tags: mesh, uv

I am a noob, but I don't reckon this is my doing.
I have a simple low poly fruit bowl. When I enter uv mapping, and synch it, the map shows the flat bottom geometry both inside and out, and also the rim. However, all quads on the faces, both inside and out, are missing.
When I select any of them they appear on the map as either an orange line between rim and bottom ( all faces in a vertical row are as 1 single line) or as a single line around the outside edge of the map.
It is a game asset, and when I upload it and apply a check cloth texture, the check appears as it should on the bottom and rim, but on both faces, it is just parallel fine wavy lines from rim to base.

I have done this in 2.83 as it has same gui as some good tutorials I have found.

Cheers.

I am hoping this can be solved without screenshot upload etc, but if needed, I will of course do that.

Comment: IMO would help if you did upload a screenshot.

Comment: also, could you add your blend file?

Comment: When you “synch it?” Wha..?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard you can sync selection between the UV Map editor and the 3D viewport. Look for the "double arrows" icon in the top left corner, it's called *"UV Sync Selection"*. However, I am not sure if that is what is meant.

Comment: It sounds like the faces appearing as UV edges aren't properly UV mapped-- mapped to zero-area faces.  A pic of the UV map with those edges selected might make that clear.  If you want these edges mapped differently, you'll need to map them.  A simple unwrap might be good for this, but it sounds like a situation where I'd recommend pinning the faces you wanted to keep first.